# How to handle multiple action types in one epic? Any cons of doing the same?

Tags: redux, observable, rxjs5, redux-observable

Pretty new to redux-observables, rxjs and observables. Wanted to know how can I handle another action, say 'ActionTwo' in the same epic

```
const Epic1 = (action$,store) => {
return action$.ofType('ActionOne')
 .mergeMap((action) => {
      return ajax({'method': 'GET', 'url': 'someUrl')
         .map(response => resultActoin(action.userId, response.response));


       }
  );
 }
```

Something like

```
const Epic1 = (action$){
   if('ActionOne') make a API call.
   if('ActionTwo') make some other API call.
   else do nothing.

}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Is it the same API call? If so, `ofType()` accepts more than one type. You can just do `action$.ofType('ActionOne', 'ActionTwo')`.

If you want to make a request to another API/URL, I would recommend to make another epic. You can "merge" all you epics with `combineEpics` see: https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/SettingUpTheMiddleware.html

Comment: ^^^ this. It's almost always better to have one epic per task

Comment: Knew about combineEpics, was trying to handle multiple actions in one epic.
Can you put some light on why having epic/per action is a good design? Other than for code maintainability?

Comment: It's only about maintainability. The reasons are the same, why you have multiple files and modules. It helps to scale and reason your applications, without little to any downside. Also, it makes refactoring more easy as well as creating you action streams.

Comment: My pleasure! :)